# Press Button and add to title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, button, if-statement

I have a post and it has a title. I want the user to be able to press a button and then after the title the word completed is placed in but I'm not sure how I would do this.

my post view looks like

```
 <% div_for post do %>
  <strong><%= link_to_unless_current h(post.title), post %></strong> - <%= link_to   post.user.name, post.user %>
  <%= simple_format h(post.body) %>
 <% end %>
```

I feel like I may need an if statement saying if clicked original code for the view plus "completed" else original code but I'm not sure how I would use this logic in a button and how to describe this logic. I'm still a noob so I'm sorry if this question is overly simple.

---

What I want to do is have a button labeled completed that adds the work complete onto the end of the title.

this is my show view

```
 <%= render :partial => @post %>

 <% if current_user?(@post.user) %>
 <p>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post)%>
<%= link_to 'Delete', @post, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
 </p>

 <% else %>
 <% end %>

 <h2>Comments</h2>
 <div id="comments">
<%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
 </div>

 <%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :body, "New Comment" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p><%= f.submit "Add Comment" %></p>
 <% end %>
```

the view in shown in my main question is the view for each individual post so basically I want to add completed in front of <%= link_to_unless_current h(post.title), post %> that block of code when I press the button and then it should display the word completed and the original title

Answer (score 0):

Im not getting your idea if what exactly shoul happen when clicking on the title, but if u want to change stuff on the fly in our html site, u need JS or ajax to handle this...

Could u please send more example code or specify what should happen or where the title should be placed?

Comment: I posted it as an answer because there was too many characters

Comment: So what you need is a link_to_remote that fires a action to your controller `<%= link_to_remote 'link_title', :url => {your_url}, :update => 'div_to_update'` %>, or i u want do do all the stuff by submitting a form, what u need is remote_form_for instead of form_for...

Comment: and u need to speficy a div like `<div id='div_to_update'></div>` where your controller renders the result into...
that would look like something like this:
<div id='my_special_div'><strong><%= link_to_unless_current h(post.title), post %></strong> - <%= link_to   post.user.name, post.user %></strong></div>

and your controller then should render the output like that:

render :inline => "<strong>Completed: <%= link_to_unless_current h(post.title), post %></strong> - <%= link_to   post.user.name, post.user %></strong>"